# Not found 404 error

Tags: php, wamp

I'm busy trying to create a website and I'm getting the Not found 404 error and I'm not sure why.

This is the whole error that I got

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /mysite/admin/menus was not found on this server
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I recently installed WAMP on my pc and then installed Laravel 5.2 with the caffeinated module package.

Comment: Can you please provide the full path with the controller and action?

Comment: Does `localhost` work? Do you see the WAMPServer home page?

Comment: yes I do see the homepage